# Server Load Check

Tags: vps, memory-usage

Is it possible to trace which file or process or database query is effecting the load on a VPS?

I am using Centos with 512 MB Guarantee Memory and 1 GB burst Memory, I am running 3 wordpress sites from it, where all are having daily traffic of 30-100 visitors each,

After every 2-3 days I need to restart my VPS because the resources are taking high usage of memory,

I tried running `top` command and it shows Apache as high,

But is it possible to check which website is taking load?

Here is my 'top -c' command output results
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could set up each wordpress site as a virtual host, and give them each seperate logfiles.
This will make it easier to see what's happening to each wordpress site.

Perhaps you could use [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) to analyze the Apache logs and get some meaningful data back.

Comment: Is there any way to check which website is having load? I have seen in Cpanels, though I Don't have cpanel, but is it possible?

Comment: I tried installing this on my server, but it extracted somewhere and how to run it? Is their any other to check which website is having more load?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set up a monitoring with [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) with the plugins you can monitor your server. But i could be a bit to much for your vps.

Comment: Nagios only show that there *is* a problem, but not the reason, especially in a case like this.

Comment: hmm? Then you should look at Nagios ;) with the plugins you can monitor your whole server. With HDD and many more? We use it for whole Server monitoring ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But still, Nagios only tells you that the disk is nearly full or the load is high or whatever, which is all nice and great, but  the OP knows there is a problem and needs to find the cause for it. Nagios doesn't help with that.

Comment: He ask if its possible to find which website or process have the load there are enough plugins for Nagios to monitor this. I use it to monitor processes and Apache processes if the load is high. [Nagios Apache2](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Web-Servers/Apache/Check-Apache-Load/details). So we are both right ;) so i said its a bit to much for this problem.

Comment: Sorry, but this is nonsense. The plugin tells Nagios that the load is high. Great, but the OP already knows that and he even suspects that some WP site is the culprit. What he needs to find out is what to change to avoid it. How would Nagios help with that?

Comment: its ok ;) i use Nagios for this problems to monitor the whole process list... so i can see which process is high. Very helpful. Secondary i have written an script which makes an specified monitoring of my server processes. But if you mean its not possible its ok ;) here its working very well.

Comment: @Stony, he's already run top and knows apache process are the problem. Getting the server load, process list, or apache mod_status output delivered by nagios is not going to provide ntechi with the more fine-grained information he needs to diagnose the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mod_php, you may find Tom Boutell's post [Faster, PHP! Kill! Kill!](http://window.punkave.com/2010/03/08/faster-php-kill-kill/) helpful. I suspect you would benefit from reducing MaxClients or switching to FastCGI.